# Some query regarding bytecode and ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

this is my sample code .

```
 public void leak()
{
    super.superMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, MemLeak>();

     int i=1;
    while(true) {

        // This put method  should be called infinite times
        super.superMap.put(i,new MemLeak("test"));


        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        i++;

    }
```

My question is that , this `put()` should have been called infinite times.But , when I am trying to check the `asm` output , I can see the method is called only thrice.

```
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name,
            String desc) {
    super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);

        // keep a check whether the owner class is Map or ConcurrentHashMap     
            System.out.println("Method called..."+owner+"\t "+name+"\t "+desc);



    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the asm output"? Could you give more context here? (We don't know what your process is to convert from the first block of code to the second...)

Comment: @JonSkeet : I am using `asm` framework to modify bytecode. And I am using `ASMifier` class to view ASM equivalent output of the bytecode modification.

And I am using `MethodVisitor` class to modify bytecode.

Comment: So what modification are you performing? It's still not really clear what you're seeing where...

Comment: Within the byte code, the method invocation should appear as often as it appears in the source code which is *exactly one time*. Don’t confuse it with the loop happening when the code will be executed. I have no idea why you see it thrice.